# Logical operator || in javascript, 0 stands for Boolean false?

Tags: javascript, boolean, logical-operators, or-operator

I happened to know the following code

**Here is the code, and very simple:**

```
var test = 0 || -1 ;
console.log(test);
```

then the output in the console is **-1**

and somehow i am really new into the javascript,

all i think of is that the **0** stands for Boolean **False** in JS ,and so `||` operator seems to ignore the 0 and assign the value -1 to the variable

so am i right ? 
i just want a confirm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `||` —    `expr1 || expr2`    *(Logical OR)*

  > Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false..
- `&&` —  `expr1 && expr2` *(Logical AND)*

  > Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

All values in Javascript are either "truthy" or "falsy".
The following values are equivalent to false in **conditional statements**:

- false
- null
- undefined
- The empty string `""` (\ `''`)
- The number 0
- The number NaN

**All other values are equivalent to true.**

---

So... `var test = 0 || -1 ;` returns `-1`.

If it was  `var test  = 0 || false || undefined || "" || 2 || -1` it would return `2`

---

Logical operator on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

Comment: In [Practical Node.js](http://www.apress.com/9781430265955) there is the following code: `var user =function (ops) {
return { firstName: ops.name || 'John', lastName: ops.name || 'Doe', email: ops.email || 'test@test.com', name:function () {return this .firstName +this .lastName}}}` -- So, I'm guessing it assigns the first values if they're "truthy" (defined) else the second values are defaults?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Yes that is correct. || and && do not (necessarily) return boolean values. They can be better described as operand selector operators. In case of || if the first operand can be coerced to true, the first operand is returned, else the second operand is returned.
The && has the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that
> returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is
> null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

Only null and undefined will be falsey. 0 will be considered true. But take care: an empty string will be considered true too!

```js
console.log('0 ?? 1  ->', 0 ?? 1) // expected output: 0
console.log('null ?? 1  -> ', null ?? 1) // expected output: 1
console.log('undefined ?? 1  ->', undefined ?? 1) // expected output: 1
console.log('"" ?? 1  ->', "" ?? 1) // expected output: ""
```