# || in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

Can somebody please tell me what || this doing here

```
(function()
{
window.myapp = window.myapp || {};
window.myapp.lang = window.myapp.lang || {};
myapp.lang.Extend = function(subClass, superClass)
{
subClass.prototype = new superClass();
};
})();
```

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: [Logical operator || in javascript, 0 stands for Boolean false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579262/logical-operator-in-javascript-0-stands-for-boolean-false)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this construct (x = x || y) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.myapp = window.myapp || {};
```

It means: create window.myapp as an empty object if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 2):

The `a = a || b;` syntax is equivalent to

```
if (!a)
  a = b;
```

or

```
a = a ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.myapp = window.myapp || {};
```

is equivalent to this code

```
if(!(window.myapp)) {
  window.myapp = {};
}
```

Comment: Why the additional parens in `!(window.myapp)` instead of `!window.myapp`?

Comment: @KitSunde just to be sure that negation applies to the whole expression. Probably we don't need it here.

Answer (score 2):

`||` is the logical OR operator in Javascript. 
In this case

`window.myapp = window.myapp || {};`

assigns `window.myapp` to itself if it is not null or false, otherwise it assigns an empty object `{}` to `window.myapp`.

Comment: *"if it is not null or false"* ...or one of four other falsey values... `NaN`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`

Answer (score 0):

|| is a [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator

while evaluating x || y , x is evaluated first, if it is true - then there is no need to evaluate y because the operation is anyway going to be true.

in javascript the following values result in 'false' when used as if condition -

> 0  -0 null "" false undefined NaN

so in your case if window.myapp is 'undefined', that will be evaluated to 'false', and the or operator has to evaluate the next operand {} to complete the operation, which is assigned to `window.myapp`

so all it is doing is -

```
if(!(window.myapp)) {
  window.myapp = {};
}
```