# Two pipe symbols (OR) in this Javascript line

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

I have seen this in JS:

```
item = item || {};
```

I'm guessing it's some variation of a ternary operator but what does is actually do?

Comment: Are we getting some Javascript snobbs in the house tonight downvoting or just general silly people!?

Comment: @Martin. and what would you suggest I could have searched to receive this answer...

Comment: good question. I have been searching for a while and finally [got it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579262/logical-operator-in-javascript-0-stands-for-boolean-false). But to be honest, it isn't as easy as I thought. Reverting all my downvotes

Comment: @Martin. Thank you. As a self taught developer, believe me, if I could have Googled it...I would have.

Comment: @ben yep, I've had a discussion about this on meta (now lost). Yep, it is really hard to search for such operators.

Comment: @Martin, may be it's been answered million times but these answers are not wrong in context and it's wrong to down vote a right answer. Well, you mentioned cwolves that why he didn't voted it to close the answer but my question is why you didn't voted to close the question ?

Comment: @Martin. I understand but none deserve a down vote for a poor answer unless it's wrong, you may don't up vote it and could have made a comment.

Comment: But finally you removed your down votes, that's a good thing. :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera two of them are wrong, they words like `if item exist` or `if item is not defined`, this is wrong since they don't cover all possibilities. But he still did wrong because he dv because other reasons

Comment: After all, I got downvoted into oblivion - just as I expected :)

Comment: @Martin. I try not to get too worked up over imaginary internet points.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
(expr1 || expr2)
```

> "Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2."

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

So when `expr1` is (or evaluates to) one of these `0,"",false,null,undefined,NaN`, then `expr2` is returned, otherwise `expr1` is returned

Answer (score 12):

It's called redundancy, but in this case it's a good thing. Basically, if `item` is not defined (or otherwise falsy (`false`, `0`, `""`...), then we give it a default value.

Most common example is in events:

```
evt = evt || window.event;
```

Answer (score 8):

If item exists, set item to item, or set it to `{}`

Comment: you don't deserve a down vote.

Comment: @Sheikh yeah, the answer isn't wrong, but it's pretty poor I think. Kolink and ajax have the best answers here. Especially Kolink deserves the upvote

Answer (score 2):

It equates to:

```
if( !item ){ item = {}; }
```

Comment: So if item is FALSE then item is an empty object?

Comment: `false` or `undefined` or any other falsey value, yes

Comment: This question has been answered million times, plus this answer is quite poor

Comment: The question, maybe.  Nothing wrong with my answer.

Comment: @cwolves you're >10k, you should vote to close the question instead. It is EXACT duplicate