# Logical operator || returns number instead of boolean value

Tags: javascript

I attached an example with two if conditions. The first if condition works as expected. The second if condition returns 11, but why? I know that the second if condition is wrong, but I would like to understand why Javascript returns in that case 11.

```
function exception(number) {
// if(number === 10 || number === 11) { // Working as expected
   if(number === 10 || 11) { // Why 11?
        console.log(number);
   }
}

function loop(f) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        f(i);
    }
}

loop(exception);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two pipe symbols (OR) in this Javascript line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358823/two-pipe-symbols-or-in-this-javascript-line)

Comment: Any non-zero number is considered truthy and will return `true` when converted to a boolean.

Comment: fyi: sometimes it's handy to just do `if ( [10,11].indexOf(number) !== -1 )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Information about what you where trying to achieve:

- `number === 10 || number === 11` is the same as `(number === 10) || (number === 11)`
- `number === 10 || 11` is the same as `(number === 10) || (11)` it does not compare `11` to `number` here

Now let's have a closer look at`number === 10 || 11` :

- `number === 10` will be `true` if number is of type number and equal to 10
- if the first was false, it will evaluate the boolean value of the next statement: `11` (wich is accepted as true, for beeing a number not equal to 0)

Comment: You can add explanation about the operator precedence

Comment: @CodeiSir: Thanks. Now I got it.

Answer (score 6):

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358823/two-pipe-symbols-or-in-this-javascript-line).

```
(expr1 || expr2)
```

> "Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2."

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

So when `expr1` is (or evaluates to) one of these `0,"",false,null,undefined,NaN`, then `expr2` is returned, otherwise `expr1` is returned

Comment: I like this answer because you actually address *why* the conditional expression is returning 11

Comment: I think he knows that, the problem was that he thought `number === 10 || number === 11` would be the same as `number === 10 || 11`

Answer (score 0):

because `Boolean(11)` is `true` (try on your console)

so even if first condition is not true (if the number is not 10), then second condition will be true always