# How can a variable be used if it's outside of curly braces in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am not understanding this - how can a `var` that's defined within an `if` condition be used outside of that condition?

Example JS:

```
if (1===2) {
  var myVar = "I live in brackets";
}
$("#debug").append("myVar = " + myVar);
$("#debug").append("but I'm about to throw a 'not defined' exception right... now " + firstAppearanceVar);
```

Renders: `myVar = I live in brackets`

Isn't `myVar`'s scope only inside of that `if (1===2)` condition?

Comment: In javascript, scope is by function. `if(){}` does not have its own scope

Comment: MDN is a great resource for learning javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope

Answer (score 2):

Scopes only apply to functions, not other blocks.

Comment: so, definitely a difference between JS and C# in that matter, for sure.

Comment: Considering the names are different, yeah, I'll say they're different!

Comment: I just say that b/c the syntax is similar in both languages.

Comment: @IanDavis, no, C# and js are completely different. [js has truthy values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9579290/601179), unlike C#. a lot of differences. ohh and C# isn't a dynamic language... a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does **not** have *block scope*, it only has *function scope*.

In other words, variables declared by `var` are accessible within the scope of a *function*, everywhere, just there, not outside.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), every variable declaration pops to the top of the function scope.

```
alert(foo); // undefined (no error because of the hoisting.)
var foo = 2;
alert(bar); Error
```

Comment: but, I don't have any functions on the page. in that case, does JS just treat this all as under the umbrella of one wrapper function?

Comment: @IanDavis, if it's not in a function it's inside the global object.

Answer (score 0):

When a javascript variable is defined, the declaration is hoisted to the top of the function scope.

So this:

```
if (1===2) {
  var myVar = "I live in brackets";
}
$("#debug").append("myVar = " + myVar);
$("#debug").append("but I'm about to throw a 'not defined' exception right... now " + firstAppearanceVar);
```

is equivalent to this

```
var myVar;
if (1===2) {
  myVar = "I live in brackets";
}
$("#debug").append("myVar = " + myVar);
$("#debug").append("but I'm about to throw a 'not defined' exception right... now " + firstAppearanceVar);
```

Any variable defined in a function therefore, is accessible anywhere in that function, or inside any inner functions.  They are not accessible outside the function.

so

```
(function(){
    if (1===2) {
      var myVar = "I live in brackets";
}}())
$("#debug").append("myVar = " + myVar); //reference exception
```