# Short-Circuiting to Print Every Value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, modulo, short-circuiting

Here is my code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  let output = "";

  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    output += "Cool";
  }
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    output += "Breeze";
  }
  console.log(output || i);
}
```

In this code, I use a for loop to vary the value of the binding i from 0 to 100.

In the first if statement, I use the modulo and the addition assignment operator to add the string "Cool" to the binding *output*.

In the second if statement, I use the modulo and the addition assignment operator to add the string "Breeze" to the binding *output*.

The function of my last statement in the body of my for loop is to print the value of the output binding in the browser console. I do this through short-circuiting. Now, I understand the logic of short-circuiting with the "OR" operator, since the interpreter will short-circuit its full logic of comparing both operands and automatically choose the operand on the left if it can be converted to `true`, which strings and numbers can, so the operand *output* is always going to be chosen.

What I don't understand is why short-circuiting is needed to visibly print every value in the console. If I were to use the statement `console.log(output);` it consolidates the number type values, stating how many were printed in a row before it had to print a string.

Can someone please explain this logic? Why is short-circuiting needed here to prevent the consolidation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operator || in javascript, 0 stands for Boolean false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579262/logical-operator-in-javascript-0-stands-for-boolean-false)

Comment: [Also relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them).

Comment: Simply put, when you OR values, you get he first *truthy* value. So, if `output` has been changed, it will be truthy, so `output || i` will return `output`, however if `output = ""`, the empty string is *falsy*, so `output || i` returns `i`

Comment: That simply explains the logic of short-circuiting. I already understand that 0, NaN, and empty strings count as false, and would never be chosen if they were the left operand.

Comment: If you just `console.log(output)`, then for `i` equal to `0`, `1`, `2`, `4`, `6` and so on, you're only printing an empty string and you never print the number.

Comment: What you are asking is why can you not just simply do `console.log(output)`? You can do it and it should work well the only difference is that it will print empty string when `i` is neither a multiple of 3 nor multiple of 5.

Comment: Thank you, VLAZ and John David, I just had a eureka moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I were to use the statement console.log(output); it consolidates the number type values, stating how many were printed in a row before it had to print a string.

In case it isn't clear to others, what you're referring to is this:

[image]

This is an artifact of the *browser console*, which consolidates duplicate logs together, to make debugging easier. Here, it's consolidating the duplicate logged empty strings. It's not a issue with your code's logic. If you were to log the output by *any other method*, the blank outputs would be displayed serially, as you'd expect, rather than being clumped together:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table').children[0];

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  let output = "";

  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    output += "Cool";
  }
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    output += "Breeze";
  }
  table.innerHTML += `<tr>Cell value: ${output}</tr>`;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your code is perfectly fine, you just need to find a way to display it *other* than `console.log` so that its unintuitive clumping doesn't mess things up.

You can also turn off the grouping by unchecking "Group Similar":

[image]

Comment: "*This is an artifact of the browser console,*" it's also configurable - you can turn off the grouping behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Snow. You're right, I was referring to the artifact of grouping in the browser console. Why does short-circuiting bypass it? Is there a deeper logic, or is it pretty much "that's the way it works." Also, I tried using the template literal, like you suggested, and I still got the same result.

Comment: @Custer The `|| i` ensures that if the empty string would have been logged, the current index is logged instead, and the current index will never be duplicated, so there's no grouping.

Comment: @Custer there is nothing to do with short-circuiting. You simply print *different* lines: `0`, `1`, `2`, `Cool`, `4`, `Breeze`, etc. Since no two are the same, they aren't grouped.

Comment: If you had done `|| 'something'` instead, you'd see grouping on the `'something'`s because they'd occasionally be duplicates of what was just logged.