# Use logical operator to assign a value or 0, otherwise assign alternative

Tags: javascript

So the double pipe `||` is the [logical OR operator](https://javascript.info/logical-operators#or).

I want to create a function where it can be either `foo`, or when thats flase (or falsy?) then  it should use a default fallback. In this case 'bar'.

```js
const foo = 0;
const bar = 'somethingElse';

const qux = foo || bar;

console.log(qux); // returns 'somethingElse'
```

Now the above example will work unless foo is 0. Since JS will interpret that als falsy.

Now the following seems to be working:

```js
// ...
const qux = typeof foo !== 'undefined' ? foo : bar;
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better solution. What would be the best way of handling such a scenario?

Comment: `typeof foo !== 'undefined'` is perfectly fine. You can use a helper function if you find yourself doing this often. `function def (l, r) {return typeof l=='undefined'?l:r}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`||` checks for the first operand to be falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9579262/1048572) (`false` when coerced to a boolean), and `0` is exactly that.

If you want to check for `null` and `undefined` only, you can use the [nullish-coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
const qux = foo ?? bar;
```

If you want to check for exactly `undefined`, you should use the conditional operator as you did.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about this operator yet, but it's exactly what you need in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is only if `foo` is `0`.
So you can modify the condition like this. This will work for everything as expected.

`const qux3 = ((foo === 0 && foo) || foo) || bar;`