# How to reduce the condition much as possible

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't understand the behavior I have in my condition. I try to reduce the code as much as possible.
With this condition I want to know if `r.user.id` or `r.user.uid` is equal to `getUser.uid`.
https://jsbin.com/zakofusiga/edit?js,console

```
let getUser = { uid: "123" };
let r = { user: { id: "toto", uid: "123"}}

if (r.user && (r.user?.id === getUser?.uid || r.user?.uid === getUser?.uid)) { ... }
```

To do so I made this code so below. It works but I don't understand why  `r?.user?.id||uid === getUser?.uid` me returns `toto` is not a boolean. Does this code work like the one above?

```
if (r?.user?.id||uid === getUser?.uid) {
  console.log("test 1", r?.user?.id||uid === getUser?.uid);
}

if (r.user?.id === getUser?.uid) {
  console.log("test 2");
}
               
if (r.user?.uid === getUser?.uid) {
  console.log("test 3");
}
```

Comment: What is `r?.user?.id||uid === getUser?.uid` supposed to be? It's currently `r?.user?.id || (uid === getUser?.uid)` ([see here for what it does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9579262)). Did you mean `(r?.user?.id || uid) === getUser?.uid` or something else? And what's `uid`?

Comment: You could destructure the nested user `const { id, uid } = r.user ?? {}` and then use `if (r.user && [id,uid].includes(getUser?.uid) )`

Comment: Also there is no need to do optional chaining in `r.user?.id` since you are already checking `r.user` before

Comment: What's the point of adding a question mark after `getUser`? Isn't `getUser` always defined? The same for `r?`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to verify that `getUser.uid` is equal to `r.user.id` or to `r.user.uid` (the first one that exists)?

Comment: With this condition I want to know if `r.user.id` or `r.user.uid` is equal to `getUser.uid`

Answer (score 1):

As VLAZ said, `|||` isn't the logical OR operator, it's a syntax error. (It looks like the logical OR operator  [`||`] followed by the bitwise OR operator [`|`], but you can't do that because you need an operand between them). You want just `||` (the logical OR operator).

I'm assuming in your real code `r.user` may be `undefined` or `null` (and similarly for `getUser`), otherwise all those optional chaining operators are unnecessary.

`r.user?.id` will be `undefined` if `r.user` is `undefined` or `null`. So will `getUser?.uid` (if `getUser` is `undefined` or `null`). Assuming you don't want to match in the `undefined` case, you'll need to check for that.

Given that, your first example is probably as concise as it's going to get, or perhaps more explicitly:

```
if (r.user?.id !== undefined && (r.user?.id === getUser?.uid || r.user?.uid === getUser?.uid)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you might consider adding a variable:

```
const gid = getUser?.uid;
if (gid !== undefined && (r.user?.id === gid || r.user?.uid === gid)) {
    // ...
}
```

Add a `?` after `r` if `r` itself may be `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are too many and unnecessarily complicated. It's not clear for me what do you want to achieve with this code, so I assume its purpose is to verify that `getUser.uid` is equal to `r.user.id` or `r.user.uid` (the first one that exists).

I would extract the two values in two variables:

```js
const id1 = getUser.uid;
const id2 = r.user?.id || r.user?.uid;
```

Here `id1` is either `getUser.uid` (if `getUser` has the property `uid`) or `undefined` otherwise.

`id2` is the first one that matches:

- `r.user.id`, if `r` has the property `user` that is an object having the property `id`;
- `r.user.uid`, if `r.user` does not have `id` but has `uid`;
- `undefined` if `r` does not have `user` or `r` has `user` but `r.user` does not have `id` and `uid`.

Now all you have to do is to compare `id1` to `id2`, possibly with a guard against `undefined`:

```js
if (id1 !== undefined && id1 === id2) {
  console.log('yes!');
}
```

Comment: if both `r.user.id` and `r.user.uid` should be compared against `getUser.uid`, you cannot simply compare "`id2` is the _first_ one that matches..." You have to check both.

Comment: "Both" means `&&`. The code in the question uses `||`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest -

```js
function userMatches (getUser, r)
{ if (getUser && r?.user)
    return r.user.id === getUser.uid
        || r.user.uid === getUser.uid
  else
    return false
}
```

Or using default arguments, something like -

```js
const userMatches = ({ uid = 0 }, { user = {} }) =>
  user.id === uid || user.uid === uid
```